# Passing React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, components, state

I have a modal that I want to appear on a button click. This works fine, however, in order for it to be positioned correctly, I need to move the modal component to be rendered in a parent component.
I'm unsure how to do this as I'm not sure how I would pass the state down to the component where the button click is created. I'm also unsure of whether this is about passing a state or using a button onClick outside the component the state is defined in.

My code works and does what I want, but, I need `<DeleteWarehouseModal show={show} />` to be in the parent component below. How can I do this?

The parent component where I want to render my modal:

```
function WarehouseComponent(props) {
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
          <WarehouseListItems warehouseData={props.warehouseData} />
          //Modal component should go here
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

The component (WarehouseListItems) where the modal is currently being rendered:

```
function WarehouseListItem(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
     <>
//some code necessary to the project, but, irrelevant to this issue

        <Link>
          <div onClick={() => setShow(true)}></div>
        </Link>
      <DeleteWarehouseModal show={show} />
     </>
  );
}
```

The modal:

```
const DeleteWarehouseModal = (props) => {
  if (!props.show) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    //some elements here
  );
};
```

Comment: Just put WarehouseListItem, where you want to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move the state and it's handler in `WarehouseComponent` component and pass the handler down to child component, which can change the state in parent component.

`WarehouseComponent` :-

```
function WarehouseComponent(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleShow = () => {
    setShow(state => !state);
  }
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
          <WarehouseListItems 
            warehouseData={props.warehouseData}
            toggleShow={toggleShow}
          />
          <DeleteWarehouseModal show={show} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

`WarehouseListItems` : -

```
function WarehouseListItem(props) {
  const {toggleShow} = props;

  return (
     <>
//some code necessary to the project, but, irrelevant to this issue

        <Link>
          <div onClick={() => toggleShow()}></div>
        </Link>
      
     </>
  );
}
```